# A simple assembly program?

Tags: assembly, masm

I've recently learned how to use MASM from MSVC++ IDE, and to test whether it works, I would like to run a short program.

However, I don't know any assembly yet (that which I do is useless: ie: even though I know what `i+=1;` is in C++, I can't do anything without `int main()`).

So where can I find a simple assembly program akin to the helloworld program used with C++? (It doesn't actually have to display "Hello, World!", it just has to do something so that I can make sure the set-up I have works).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the MASM documentation online:
http://web.sau.edu/LillisKevinM/csci240/masmdocs/

Here is the difinitive tutorial on assembly:
http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/

I think that between the two of those you should be able to get up to speed and start writing programs.

Answer (score 1):

To get you into a quick start I would suggest the following sites:
[RADasm](http://www.oby.ro/rad_asm/) and [WinASM](http://www.winasm.net/).

From these sites you can find some examples, some prepackaged downloads with IDE and compiler. This way it is actually pretty easy to do some GUI-software early on but be warned, take care to read about x86 assembly. Check out [wikibooks - x86 assembler](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
global _main

_main:
mov ax, 0x01
mov bx, 0x02

inc ax
inc bx

jmp _main
```

Explanation:

1°_ you're saying to nasm to search for a _main label: `global _main`

2°_ you're declaring the `_main` label

3°_ you're changing the value of two cpu registers: `ax` and `bx` to `0x01` and `0x02` respectively

4°_ you're incrementing the values of `ax` and `bx`

5°_ lastly, you're jumping to `_main`, this mean you are in a infinite loop

Comment: This is a MASM question, not NASM.  It might not accept the `global` directive.  Also, if you're going to prefix your labels with `_` for some reason, you want `jump _main`.

Comment: oh yeah, i forget it.

Comment: You can [edit] your answer to fix mistakes

Comment: i dont know masm's syntax

Comment: I meant fix the `main` vs. `_main` mismatch.  I did that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this site interesting:
[Authoring Windows Applications In Assembly Language](http://www.grc.com/smgassembly.htm). You can download The Small Is Beautiful Starter Kit which contains a sample application to write a Windows program in assembly.